# How to disabled Next.js production build converted my rgba color to hsla

Tags: css, next.js, rgba

I wrote CSS to show grid patterns like this:

```
background-image {
 repeating-linear-gradient( 0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.43) 0px 1px, transparent 1px 20px ), 
 repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.43) 0px 1px, transparent 1px 20px )
}
```

But after production build on Next.js, this was replaced with:

```
background-image {
 repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.43) 1px,transparent 1px 20px),
 repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.43) 1px,transparent 1px 20px)
}
```

And the grid pattern doesn't show on the page.

Is there any solution to disable this convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved to change `deg` to `to` of gradient syntax. Still use hsla but the results are same.

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.43) 0px 1px,
      transparent 1px 20px
    ),
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      to left,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.43) 0px 1px,
      transparent 1px 20px
    );
```